# Not receiving Push Notifications from CloudKit Subscriptions

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm not receiving Push Notifications I expect from `CloudKit` Subscriptions.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Enabled the `CloudKit` and Remote Notifications capabilities.
- Created a 'Test' Record Type using the CloudKit dashboard.
- Created a subscription for the appropriate record type (Test), which
  I can see in the CloudKit dashboard.
- Use a physical device to test, which is signed in to `iCloud` and
  connected to the internet.
- Set up the app delegate to receive notifications.
- Manually Inserted/Updated/Deleted records via the `CloudKit` portal.

Unfortunately I never receive any push notifications, ever. The code involved is shown below. Literally, this is the only code in a brand new blank project.

```
    // MARK: - SUBSCRIPTIONS
func subscribeToRecordChangesWithRecordType (recordType:String, database:CKDatabase) {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation|CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordDeletion|CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordUpdate)

    database.saveSubscription(subscription, completionHandler: { (savedSubscription, error) -> Void in
        if let _error = error {
            NSLog("ERROR saving '%@' subscription %@",recordType, _error)
        } else {
            NSLog("SUCCESS creating '%@' subscription: %@", recordType, savedSubscription)
        }
    })
}
func createSubscriptions () {
    let privateDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase


    // NOTE: create a Record Type called 'Test' in the CloudKit dashboard
    self.subscribeToRecordChangesWithRecordType("Test", database: privateDB)
    self.subscribeToRecordChangesWithRecordType("Test", database: publicDB)
}

// MARK: - PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
func registerForPushNotifications (application: UIApplication) {
    self.createSubscriptions()
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    NSLog("Registered for Push Notifications with token: %@", deviceToken);
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    NSLog("FAILED to register for Push Notifications. %@", error)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    NSLog("RECEIVED Push Notification")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PushNotificationReceived", object: userInfo)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    NSLog("RECEIVED LOCAL Push Notification")
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    NSLog("RECEIVED Push Notification with fetchCompletionHandler")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PushNotificationReceived", object: userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.registerForPushNotifications(application)
    return true
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions. I hope this isn't a bug and that I'm doing something wrong here ... it should 'just work'!

Cheers

Comment: The code looks OK. Are you able to query your public database for recordType Test? Can you show us what the output is of the NSLog statements? could you try executing the registerForRemoteNotifications before creating the subscriptions?

Comment: A year and now answer :(  I'm having exactly the same problem.  Surprisingly little about this topic online beyond the manual provided by Apple.

Comment: I ended up doing the sync logic myself. Check out the front page of timroadley dot com to download the code. It's the ezcloudkit.zip project

Comment: I am having the same issue- it seems to not be receiving notifications.  I wonder if its a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. You have enabled Push Notification besides CloudKit (and Background Mode if needed) in App's Capabilities tab. And if needed, find the push certificates (one for Dev, one for production) from Developer Portal, download them and install them (by double clicking on them);
2. You're testing the app on a device. Apple does not push to the simulator.